# Could someone check my proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} (a_k + b_k) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} a_k + \lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} b_k$

Let ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ be sequences of real numbers. Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} a_k = \alpha$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n}b_k = \beta$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n}  (a_k+b_k) = \delta$. Then, $|a_k - \alpha| < \epsilon/2$, when $n\ge N_1,$ for $N_1 \in \mathbf{N}$. Additionally,$|b_k -\beta|< \epsilon/2$, when $n\ge N_2,$ for $N_2 \in \mathbf{N}$. 
Thus, taking $N=$max{$N_1,N_2\}$, we see that $\alpha + \beta + 
\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $\delta, \forall n \ge N,$ where $N \in \mathbf{N}$. Then, $\alpha + \beta + \epsilon \ge \delta$,i.e., $\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} \alpha + \lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} \beta \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k\ge n} \delta$. QED

Comment: $\sup a_n$ : supremum over which $n$ ?

Comment: $a_n, b_n$ are sequences in $\mathbf{R}$, where $n \in \mathbf{Z}$

Comment: Yes,thank you for that, but over what are you taking the supremum? Usually we say "supremum of a function over some set" or "supremum of some set". What is the supremum of $a_n$ over? Are you taking over all $n \leq k$ for $k$? The point is, I think you are missing information in the question. Where have you taken this from?

Comment: My apologies, let me be more precise. The sup $a_j$/$b_j$ over $j \ge k$, for all $ n \ge k$.

Comment: That is better. So you mean : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \geq n} a_k$, right? Similarly for $b_k$ and $a_k+b_k$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for clearing it, I will answer the question. Kindly edit the question to reflect the changes. +1.

Comment: I believe it is correctly stated now.

Comment: I am just asking this : You have written "Let $\lim_{n} \sup_{k \geq n} a_k = \alpha$". Do you understand why the limit exists?(If it sounds too trivial, I apologize, but I feel this is important).

Comment: It exists because $a_k$ is bounded and we are assuming that the limit does not go to $\infty$ or -$\infty$, correct?

Comment: No, it exists because $\sup_{k \geq n} a_k$ is a *decreasing* sequence.This is bounded below by whatever bound $a_n$ has, and then we use : any monotone bounded sequence is convergent.